# Linq2SQL InfoMessage

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datacontext

is it possible to access the InfoMessage event handler in a Linq2SQL data context? All of our code uses these messages to display useful information to the end user and since moving to Linq2SQL I cannot figure out how to show these messages. I have checked the connection object of the data context as well as the classes properties with no luck so I'm wondering if it is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried hooking up to the Log of the datacontext?

Comment: also, you can still get the Connection off the datacontext, cast to sqlconnection (since it's linq2sql, that should be safe :) and then hook up to infomessage like you did before (I would think, haven't tried it myself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to simply cast the context's connection to a `SqlConnection` and then hook up your info message handling routine:

```
YourDataContext ctx = new YourDataContext();

SqlConnection con = (cufe.Connection as SqlConnection);

if(con != null)
{  
    con.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(con_InfoMessage);
}
```

and then of course implement that `SqlInfoMessageEventHandler` in your code.

Comment: @Paul Oakham: ok, so if it works great and thus solved your problem, please **accept** this answer - click on the big checkmark to the left of the question.